# theming sencha touch error: File to import not found or unreadable: sencha-tou ch/default/all

Tags: sencha-touch

I just cant find a workarround for this, please help

my config.rb in location $PROJECT_HOME/assets/www/theming

```
 dir = File.dirname('..Path_to_project_home..\assets\www\theming\config.rb')


load File.join(dir, '..', 'lib', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')


sass_path    = dir
css_path     = dir
environment  = :production
output_style = :compressed
```

this is my app.scss:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

@include sencha-panel;
@include sencha-buttons;
@include sencha-toolbar;
@include sencha-list;
@include sencha-layout;
@include sencha-sheet;
@include sencha-msgbox;
```

in the console in the directory of the 'sass_path' I run

```
compass compile app.scss
```

but I get the following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: sencha-touch/default/all.
```

Please help, cant solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why this is nowhere mentioned, maybe because it´s straight forward. I copied the

```
<sencha-root>/resources/themes Folder
```

into my project:

```
<project-root>/lib/touch/resources/themes
```

as it is declared in the .join command in this line

```
load File.join(dir, '..', 'lib', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')
```

after running

```
compass compile yourApp.scss
```

in the theming directory of the project again, it should work now.

Comment: You don't need to copy anything - see my other post!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to copy anything here, the key is in the config.rb file. You will see a line like:

```
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')
```

This tells compass where to load sencha touch's sass files from. It translates as:

```
../../touch/resources/themes
```

So, if you imagine using cd to move directories to the ST themes directory, that's what you need to amend the File.join line to. For example if your directory structure was as follows:

/stuff
  /resources
    /sass
      config.rb
/vendor
  /sencha-touch.2.2.1
    /resources
      /themes

You would need a line like:

```
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', '../', 'vendor', 'sencha-touch.2.2.1', 'resources', 'themes')
```

If in doubt, just go to the directory with your config.rb and perfect a cd which takes you to th

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify dan's correct answer, you might have to create the folders 
**lib** with **touch** in it 
and **resources** inside **touch** 
in your  folder 
and then copy the **themes** folder from your /resources/themes folder into the **resources** folder.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any help online so I did this

```
@import '../../../sdk/resources/themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/all';
```

Totally nailed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

try to modify config.rb

this line :

```
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', '../..', 'resources', 'themes')
```

to :

```
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', '..', 'resources', 'themes')
```

or :
count the point te reach the path level of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone hits this... I ran into this problem after converting an existing non-Cmd app to run under Cmd. Eventually I realized that I already had `compass watch` running in a terminal window for the existing app, and so the changes to `config.rb` to add the Touch path were not reflected. After I simply restarted compass and updated the sass file everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading sencha SDK from 2.1.1 to 2.2.2

The problem for me was that, while creating the default workspace for the projects, Sencha does not copy all the necessary file into the

```
<workspace-name>/touch/resources/themes
```

folder.

So I copied, to dan, the

```
 /touch-2.2.1/resources/themes
```

into the workspace's

```
touch/resources
```

folder, and so all worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird version of this same problem: it would only occur when I saved the app.scss file while in SCSS Mode in Emacs! I switched back to fundamental-mode and saved it and it works fine. Don't ask me why.